# how do i call the previous page's random value to another page?

Tags: php, forms

Guys this is my main page

```
<?php
$random = rand(4, 5);
$random2 = rand(1, 12);
$random3 = rand(1, 60);
$random4 = rand(1, 60);
$random5 = rand(1, 60);

if ($random2 % 4 != 0) {
$random2 += 4 - ($random2 % 4);
$call = $random;
} else {
$random2 += 4 - ($random2 % 4);
$call = $random2;
}

$answer = $random * $random2;
?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/main.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/easy2.css" type="text/css"/>

    <title> Easy Game 2 </title>
<center>
    <h1> Easy Game 2 </h1>
    <h2> Multiple Choice! </h2>
    <div class="border_solid">
        <div id="timer"></div>
    </div>
    <hr>
</center>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="doeasygame2.php">
    <table cellspacing="40" class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="question_1"><?php echo $random; ?> X <?php echo $random2; ?> =?</label>
                <input type="radio" id="mcq" name="mcq" value="<?php echo $random3; ?>"><?php echo $random3; ?>
                <input type="radio" id="mcq" name="mcq" value="<?php echo $random4; ?>"><?php echo $random4; ?>
                <input type="radio" id="mcq" name="mcq" value="<?php echo $random5; ?>"><?php echo $random5; ?>
                <input type="radio" id="mcq" name="mcq" value="<?php echo $answer; ?>"><?php echo $answer; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" class="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/><br>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myVar = setInterval(function () {
    myTimer()
}, 1000);
var d = 0;

function myTimer() {
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = d++;
}

</script>
</html>
```

and this is my do page to check the easygame page after the user has clicked on all the radio buttons that he/she selected on each question,it will bring to the dopage to verify if he/she's answer that he/she's submitted is correct or wrong.

```
<?php

$random = isset($_POST['random']) ? intval($_POST['random']) : 0;
$random2 = isset($_POST['random2']) ? intval($_POST['random2']) : 0;
$random3 = isset($_POST['random3'])? intval($_POST['random3']) : 0;
$random4 = isset($_POST['random4'])? intval($_POST['random4']) : 0;
$random5 = isset($_POST['random5'])? intval($_POST['random5']) : 0;
$answer = isset($_POST['answer'])? intval($_POST['answer']) : 0;
$mcq = $_POST['mcq'];
?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/main.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/easy2.css" type="text/css"/>

    <title> Easy Game 2 </title>
<center>
    <h1> Easy Game 2 </h1>
    <h2> Multiple Choice! </h2>
    <hr>
</center>
</head>
<body>
<table cellspacing="40" class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="question_1"><?php echo $random; ?> X <?php echo $random2; ?> =?</label>
            <input type="radio" id="mcq" name="mcq" value="<?php echo $random3; ?>"><?php echo $random3; ?>
            <input type="radio" id="mcq" name="mcq" value="<?php echo $random4; ?>"><?php echo $random4; ?>
            <input type="radio" id="mcq" name="mcq" value="<?php echo $random5; ?>"><?php echo $random5; ?>
            <input type="radio" id="mcq" name="mcq"><?php echo $answer; ?>
            <?php
            if ($mcq == $answer) {
                echo "Correct!";
            } else {
                echo "Wrong!";
            }
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Why is it that when i click on the radio button from the first page and submit it, the values on the next page is 0 and the answer i validated is wrong?

Comment: but i did put a name under the radio button called mcq, why is it not coming out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reviewed your code and found that you have not storing options in the first page and when you are trying to post it on next page it will become zero because all the radio button have same name and when you post it on the next page it will only post the selected radio value.

For fulfill your requirement you just need to use below my code as a first page:

```
<?php
$random = rand(4, 5);
$random2 = rand(1, 12);
$random3 = rand(1, 60);
$random4 = rand(1, 60);
$random5 = rand(1, 60);

if ($random2 % 4 != 0) {
$random2 += 4 - ($random2 % 4);
$call = $random;
} else {
$random2 += 4 - ($random2 % 4);
$call = $random2;
}

$answer = $random * $random2;
?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/main.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/easy2.css" type="text/css"/>

    <title> Easy Game 2 </title>
<center>
    <h1> Easy Game 2 </h1>
    <h2> Multiple Choice! </h2>
    <div class="border_solid">
        <div id="timer"></div>
    </div>
    <hr>
</center>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="doeasygame2.php">
<table cellspacing="40" class="table">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="question_1"><?php echo $random; ?> X <?php echo $random2; ?> =?</label>
                <input type="radio" id="mcq" name="mcq" value="<?php echo $random3; ?>"><?php echo $random3; ?>
                <input type="radio" id="mcq" name="mcq" value="<?php echo $random4; ?>"><?php echo $random4; ?>
                <input type="radio" id="mcq" name="mcq" value="<?php echo $random5; ?>"><?php echo $random5; ?>
                <input type="radio" id="mcq" name="mcq" value="<?php echo $answer; ?>"><?php echo $answer; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" class="submit" value="submit" name="submit"/><br>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="hidden" name="random" value="<?php print $random ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="random2" value="<?php print $random2 ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="random3" value="<?php print $random3 ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="random4" value="<?php print $random4 ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="random5" value="<?php print $random5 ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="answer" value="<?php print $answer ?>">
</form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
var myVar = setInterval(function () {
    myTimer()
}, 1000);
var d = 0;

function myTimer() {
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = d++;
}

</script>
</html>
```

Please use below code for second page:

```
<?php

$random = isset($_POST['random']) ? intval($_POST['random']) : 0;
$random2 = isset($_POST['random2']) ? intval($_POST['random2']) : 0;
$random3 = isset($_POST['random3'])? intval($_POST['random3']) : 0;
$random4 = isset($_POST['random4'])? intval($_POST['random4']) : 0;
$random5 = isset($_POST['random5'])? intval($_POST['random5']) : 0;
$answer = isset($_POST['answer'])? intval($_POST['answer']) : 0;
$mcq = $_POST['mcq'];
?>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/main.css" type="text/css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/easy2.css" type="text/css"/>

    <title> Easy Game 2 </title>
<center>
    <h1> Easy Game 2 </h1>
    <h2> Multiple Choice! </h2>
    <hr>
</center>
</head>
<body>
<table cellspacing="40" class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label for="question_1"><?php echo $random; ?> X <?php echo $random2; ?> =?</label>
            <input type="radio" id="mcq" name="mcq" value="<?php echo $random3; ?>" <?php print $random3 == $mcq ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?> ><?php echo $random3; ?>
            <input type="radio" id="mcq" name="mcq" value="<?php echo $random4; ?>" <?php print $random4 == $mcq ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?> ><?php echo $random4; ?>
            <input type="radio" id="mcq" name="mcq" value="<?php echo $random5; ?>" <?php print $random5 == $mcq ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?> ><?php echo $random5; ?>
            <input type="radio" id="mcq" name="mcq" <?php print $mcq == $answer ? 'checked="checked"' : '' ?> ><?php echo $answer; ?>
            <?php
            if ($mcq == $answer) {
                echo "Correct!";
            } else {
                echo "Wrong!";
            }
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: is there a way to show the selected radio button on the do page? @Er Sharad Soni

Comment: Welcome.....if you happy with my answer, so please put my answer correct. Thanks.

Comment: Please replace "<input type="radio" id="mcq" name="mcq"><?php echo $answer; ?>"  to "<input type="radio" id="mcq" name="mcq" checked="checked"><?php echo $answer; ?>" on the second page.

Comment: Is this the above comment is helpful for you or not ??

Comment: which page do i put it in? if i put it on the do page, do i have to do for all the input? because what if the user checks another radio button? @Er Sharad Soni

Comment: Yes, it is helpful! @Er Sharad Soni

Comment: which page do i put it in? if i put it on the do page, do i have to do for all the input? because what if the user checks another radio button? @Er Sharad Soni

Comment: I have added second page as well. Please use it.

Comment: so you mean i have to put checked="checked" for both pages? @Er Sharad Soni